# Suppress BOM in HTML output of UTF-8 listings

Tags: unicode, tex4ht, listingsutf8

I include some listings into my LaTeX code using

```
\lstinputlisting[inputencoding=utf8/latin1]{listing.txt}
```

The listings are taken from files which are encoded using UTF-8 (with BOM).
The LaTeX file is encoded using UTF-8 without BOM.

When compiling my code with XeLaTeX to PDF everything works fine, however when compiling it with tex4ht I get the string `ï»¿` at the begin of the actual listing (which seems to come from the BOM character `U+FEFF`).

Is there a way to suppress it?

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Files are encoded using UTF-8
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %The text uses German umlauts
\usepackage{listingsutf8}       
\lstset{literate=%
    {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
    {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
    {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
    {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
    {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
    {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
    {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
    {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
    {ű}{{\H{u}}}1 {Ű}{{\H{U}}}1 {ő}{{\H{o}}}1 {Ő}{{\H{O}}}1
    {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1
    {ã}{{\~a}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
    {ø}{{\o}}1 {€}{{\EUR}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1
    {~}{{\textasciitilde}}1
}
\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[language={},inputencoding=utf8/latin1]{listing.txt}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably simplest way would be to remove the `BOM` from the included files. The other solution is to use Unicode TeX engine, which means `LuaTeX` as `tex4ht` doesn't support `XeTeX` at the moment. There are two possible solutions to get your file working with `tex4ht` and `LuaTeX`:

replace `inputenc` with `luainputenc`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc} %Files are encoded using UTF-8
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %The text uses German umlauts
\usepackage{listingsutf8}       
\lstset{literate=%
    {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
    {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
    {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
    {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
    {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
    {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
    {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
    {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
    {ű}{{\H{u}}}1 {Ű}{{\H{U}}}1 {ő}{{\H{o}}}1 {Ő}{{\H{O}}}1
    {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1
    {ã}{{\~a}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
    {ø}{{\o}}1 {€}{{\EUR}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1
    {~}{{\textasciitilde}}1
}
\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[language={},inputencoding=utf8/latin1]{listing.txt}
\end{document}
```

Use a trick to get `fontspec` package [working with tex4ht](http://michal-h21.github.io/samples/helpers4ht/fontspec.html). This way, it works with `tex4ht`, `LuaTeX` and even `XeTeX`:

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc} %Files are encoded using UTF-8
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %The text uses German umlauts
\usepackage{alternative4ht}
\altusepackage{fontspec}
% \usepackage{listingsutf8}       
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{literate=%
    {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
    {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
    {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
    {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
    {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
    {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
    {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
    {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
    {ű}{{\H{u}}}1 {Ű}{{\H{U}}}1 {ő}{{\H{o}}}1 {Ő}{{\H{O}}}1
    {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1
    {ã}{{\~a}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
    {ø}{{\o}}1 {€}{{\EUR}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1
    {~}{{\textasciitilde}}1
}
\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[language={},inputencoding=utf8/latin1]{listing.txt}
\end{document}
```

In both cases compile it with

```
make4ht -ul filename
```

the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @michal.h21 , it works now!
Please note that I edited my question and removed the spurious lines `\begin{lstlisting}[language={}]` and `\end{lstlisting}`which were left from another example. You could edit your answer and remove them too.